# String template using concrete implementation instead of external library

Tags: c#

Q1: What are the benefits of using any external library `e.g Antlr3.StringTemplate`?

Q2: What are the potential issues with the below implementation?

```
public class StringTemplate
{
    private string text = string.Empty;
    public StringTemplate(string template)
    {
        this.text = template;
    }

    public StringTemplate SetAttribute(string attribute, object value)
    {
        text = text.Replace($"${attribute}$", value?.ToString() ?? "");
        return this;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return text.ToString();
    }
}
```

**And use it like below**

```
 private void writeMsg()
 {
     var email = "Dear $name$...";//Loading from html file place holder used pattern $placeholder$.

     var template =
         new StringTemplate(email)
         .SetAttribute("name", "John");

     Console.WriteLine(template.ToString());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

One probable issue is performance, suppose there are 30 tokens to be replaced. And email template has a size of 50 kb. strings are immutable in C#/.Net. That means whenever you call `StringTemplate.SetAttribute` it creates a new string by manipulating existing and return the new string. suppose there are 30 tokens so it will create 50KB * 29 waste string. It will create more pressure on GC and GC will collect more often which will lead to poor performance. Better to use `List<char>` to do this kind of operation.

Comment: Can you paste some code samples? It would be more helpful.